# Reading Strings from lines in Java

Tags: java, string, special-characters, readline

I have a txt file formatted like:

```
Name 'Paul' 9-years old
```

How can I get from a "readline":

```
String the_name="Paul"
```

and

```
int the_age=9
```

in Java, discarding all the rest?

I have:

```
  ...       
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

       //put the name value in the_name

       //put age value in the_age

    }
...
```

Please suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use java.util.regex.Pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Name '(.*)' (\d*)-years old");
for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String theName = matcher.group(1);
        int theAge = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `BufferedReader` and everything is on the one line, you would have to split it to extract the data. Some additional formatting is then required to remove the quotes & extract the year part of age. No need for any fancy regex:

```
String[] strings = line.split(" ");
if (strings.length >= 3) {
   String the_name= strings[1].replace("'", "");
   String the_age = strings[2].substring(0, strings[2].indexOf("-"));
}
```

I notice you have this functionality in a `while` loop. For this to work, make sure that every line keeps the format:

```
text 'Name' digit-any other text
    ^^    ^^     ^
```

Important chars are

- Spaces: min of 3 tokens needed for split array
- Single quotes
- `-` Hyphen character

Comment: I tried your solution but I have got:  "String index out of range: -1" do you have an idea of why that error would occur?

Comment: Looks like there is no `-` character present in the line probably due to your `while` loop. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.substring`, `String.indexOf`, `String.lastIndexOf`, and `Integer.parseInt` methods as follows:

```
String line = "Name 'Paul' 9-years old";
String theName = line.substring(line.indexOf("'") + 1, line.lastIndexOf("'"));
String ageStr = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("' ") + 2, line.indexOf("-years"));
int theAge = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
System.out.println(theName + " " + theAge);
```

Output:

> Paul 9